# KeyAttribute attribute does not work when setting primary key

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

The Entity Framework Core version is 7.0.10. While getting data from database, it throws out no primary key exception even I have already set it up in model class.

> The entity type 'Order' requires a primary key to be defined.

Here is the code.

```
[Table("xxxTable")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int Id;
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//Here is the method to get data from database
public async Task<Order> GetOrdersByDay(int days)
{
   Order r = await this._dbContext.Orders.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
   return r;
}
```

I have set primary key in class `Order` with attribute `[Key]`, but it does not work. The exception is still there.

If I use fluent API to set up the primary key, it is working fine.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(t => t.Id);
});
```

Why does not `[Key]` work? How can I resovle it when I only want to use attribute instead of fluent API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try adding `{ get; set; }` for the `Id`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Even if this is not the resolution to this issue, _not_ having public variables, but only public properties is a very good habit anyway.

Comment: It works after adding `{ get; set; }` !  Now it makes me confused. Previoulsy, I just thought `public int Id;` equals `public int Id { get; set; }`. It is not?

Comment: Hi @UweKeim, why is it a good habit not having public variables? Some more detail. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @UweKeim, `public int Id;`  and `public int Id { get; set; }` are not the same while using with Entity Framework Core? What is the difference?

Comment: @RobinSun They are not the same. What you had is called a field. With the `{ get; set; }` it becomes an auto property. Properties can have logic for getting and setting a value instead of storing a value directly. In this case it's an auto property that simply gets and sets an underlying field. However, libraries like EF Core likely inject their own logic in your getters and setters to accomplish their magic. It's better if you google about fields and properties in c#.